# Php curl api for sms not giving response

Tags: php, curl

```
<i><?php
    $apiKey = urlencode('ym4qoK7ier4-ekRPruxP1eqh0pPHsn9slaivPpMtZY');
    $numbers = array(917823466910, 918790650519);
    $sender = urlencode('Garry');
    $message = rawurlencode('This is your message');
    $numbers = implode(',', $numbers);
    $data = array('apikey' => $apiKey, 'numbers' => $numbers, "sender" =>    $sender, "message" => $message);
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.textlocal.in/send/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    echo $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
?></i>
```

Neither response is executing nor I am getting any message over my phone

Comment: you can try to send it via a form and see if that work. It could be the 3rd party.

Comment: I wanted to ask why this is not working...Curl responses true or false..In this case , nothing is working.

Comment: Not sure if that APIkey is valid, but running that code returns `{"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"}`

Comment: Running code return out display :- {"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"}1
Parameter is invalid .

Comment: Got the point now..Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

TextLocal expect parameters `username`,`hash`,`message`,`sender`,`numbers` and if your account is test then need to pass `test` too.try like this

```
$data = "username=".$username."&hash=".$hash."&message=".$message."&sender=".$sender."&numbers=".$numbers."&test=".$test;
```